# intellinet PVID not working

Tags: networking, vlan

I'm have a network whish we are making vlan enabled. The largest part of the network is configured and running. I only experience problems in the first switch.

So, what I have is a Watchguard sending out 3 vlans. Vlan 1 (untagged), 10 (tagged) and 20 (tagged). This goes to port 12 of an Intellinet 16/24-PORT
GIGABIT.

The SFP ports going to the secundary switches are working fine. The secondary switches are receiving and forwarding all vlans. The problem however is on port 12. If I switch port 12 to "untagged" vlan 1 is working just fine but vlan 10 and 20 are not received. If I switch to "tagged" with PVID 1, I supose the swich has to accept vlan 10 and 20 as tagged and take the untagged trafic to the PVID whish is 1. However, I loose connection with the watchguard on all client connected to VLAN 1. Even those plugged in to the Intellinet itself.

I checked the [manual](http://assets.mhint.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/353/523554_manual.pdf) what seems to confirm my way of thinking.

Is there anything I'm not thinking of? The Watchguard is managed by someone externaly so it is difficult to switch VLAN 1 to "tagged" in the Watchguard.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the support.

Comment: You usually **do not** ever tag vlan1, even on trunk ports. Make sure this is the case going all the way through the switching fabric to the end device.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart: Really? Many switches I've seen specifically have a `trunk` option that tags _everything_ and rejects untagged frames.

Comment: @grawity, weird. What manufacturer?  I have mainly been exposed to Cisco products & brocade switches. That comment was assuming this is 802.1q compliant switching where untagged vlans that pass through the switch are assumed to be the **native vlan**.